# 400 Bad Request python flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

Hi I'm new to python flask, i have what seems a simple issue of a 400 bad request error, that should be due to having wrongly named variables in form when trying to pass them to a function in python flask. I have done some research but i still can't figure out where i go wrong with this code, any help would be really appreciated.
Here is the code for the html form

```
<html>
<body>

  <h1>Add a Munroe to your list</h1>
    <form action = "{{ url_for('addmunro') }}" method="POST"
      enctype = "multipart/form-data">

      Name<br>
      <input type="text" name="mnName"/><br>
      Description<br>
      <input type="text" name="mnDesc"/><br>
      Region<br>
      <input type="text" name="mnRegion"/><br>
      Height<br>
      <input type="text" name="mnHeight"/><br>
      Walk date<br>
      <input type="text" name="mnDate"/><br>
      Walk image<br>
      <input type="text" name="mnImage"/><br>

      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="add-munro.html" value = "ADD MUNRO"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the python flask application

```
        from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, json, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/add-munro.html', methods=['GET'])
def addmunro():


    #Create an empty list
    mnList={}

    #Create a munro dictionary
    munro = {'name':request.form['mnName'],
             'desc':request.form['mnDesc'],
             'region':request.form['mnRegion'],
             'height':request.form['mnHeight'],
             'date':request.form['mnDate'],
             'image':request.form['mnImage']}

    #the munro dictionary is added to mnList
    #mnList.append(munro)

    return render_template('add-munro.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', debug = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes:

1. You are making POST request but handling only GET request
2. .html is not needed in routing
3. munro object is not passed to the template

I have updated these and now it's good to go:

`application.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)    

@app.route('/add-munro', methods=['GET','POST'])
def addmunro():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #Create an empty list
        mnList={}
        #Create a munro dictionary
        munro = {'name':request.form['mnName'],
                 'desc':request.form['mnDesc'],
                 'region':request.form['mnRegion'],
                 'height':request.form['mnHeight'],
                 'date':request.form['mnDate'],
                 'image':request.form['mnImage']}
        return render_template('add-munro.html', munro=munro)
    else:
        return render_template('add-munro.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`add-munro.html`

```
<html>
<body>
    {% if munro is defined -%}
    <h3>
        Name: {{ munro.name }}
    </h3>
    <h3>
        Description: {{ munro.desc }}
    </h3>
    <h3>
        Region: {{ munro.region }}
    </h3>
    <h3>
        Height: {{ munro.height }}
    </h3>
    {%- endif %}
    <h1>Add a Munroe to your list</h1>
    <form action = "{{ url_for('addmunro') }}" method="POST"
    enctype = "multipart/form-data">

    Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="mnName"/><br>
    Description<br>
    <input type="text" name="mnDesc"/><br>
    Region<br>
    <input type="text" name="mnRegion"/><br>
    Height<br>
    <input type="text" name="mnHeight"/><br>
    Walk date<br>
    <input type="text" name="mnDate"/><br>
    Walk image<br>
    <input type="text" name="mnImage"/><br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value = "ADD MUNRO"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i also need to upload an image as part of the dictionary, I know i have to change the type to file in the html, but how do i save in the dictionary in the flask application?

Comment: You can not save the file in the dictionary. But you can certainly save the file in a directory and then save the path in the dictionary. Use `image = request.files["mnImage"]` to get the file in the controller and then save it in a directory using `image.save()`. Finally you can return the path of the image in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a `POST` request in your form, but only allow the `GET` method in your app route. Change `@app.route('/add-munro.html', methods=['GET'])` to `@app.route('/add-munro.html', methods=['POST'])`.